# do 'blueprint shortcuts' in Sails skip validation?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

For dev I'm using 'blueprint shortcuts' in Sails to create some records quickly.

However, I now noticed that I can create multiple `Users` with the same `username` although I've specified `username` *to be unique*.

Which leads me to believe that 'blueprint shortcuts' skip Model Validation. Is this correct?

Btw: I've configured the mongo adapter, so the backend supports checking for uniqueness.

Comment: Have you verified that the uniqueness constraint is being respected when creating models programmatically (i.e. not using blueprints)?  You can try using `sails console` and creating some instances that way.  Blueprints use the same Waterline methods that you would use for custom controller actions, so chances are the issue isn't there.  If there's really a problem with uniqueness, it's more likely a bug in the `sails-mongo` adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Blueprint controller methods don't skip model validation, but I'm not sure about the "shortcuts" (you mean the shortcuts for the browser address bar right?).

Comment: yeah correct. They seem to skip the uniqueness constraint

Comment: Not sure about that then, I don't use them personally.